# Linear Algebra and Set Theory book recommendations.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, elementary-set-theory, self-learning, advice

I would like to studying linear algebra and set theory.

> Does anyone have a a good recommendation of books/resources/etc.?

Comment: 1. Avoid asking multiple questions in one thread, like two different topics for books recommendations. 2. There have been many a thread with such recommendations, use the search function before posting.

Comment: I'm a fan of Quine's *Mathematical Logic*, but I think I'm literally the only one. So count this as a recommendation if you're eccentric, or a warning if you're pretty much anybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linear Algebra, I recommend **[Linear Algebra Done Right by *Sheldon Axler*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982582)**. 
$\mathrm{}\\$For Set Theory, I recommend **[Naive Set Theory by *Paul Halmos*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1614271313)**.

Answer (score 1):

Set theory - for the beginning Naive Set Theory by Paul R. Halmos. For later Set Theory by 
Thomas Jech. Please also check this link [What are good books/other readings for elementary set theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/what-are-good-books-other-readings-for-elementary-set-theory)

Answer (score 1):

For linear algebra I can recommend: Lang, Serge (March 9, 2004), *Linear Algebra*, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics.

This one is really a good starting point into algebra and higher mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite Linear Algebra book is the one by Hoffman & Kunze. As has been said above Naive Set Theory by P.R.Halmos may be a good place to begin with.